So is multiprocessing.Manager.dict() from Python support multiple processes accessing and making changing at the same time?
I have multiple processes that will access this dictionary:
And I have multiple processes try to access and make change to it at the same time. Will there be any distribution problem? Or is the multiprocessing module takes care of it?
The actual instance is:
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
manager = Manager()
result_dict = manager.dict()
Now multiple processes are making change to result_dict at the same time.Will there be any distribution problem? Or is the multiprocessing module takes care of it?

What do you mean by "distribution problem"?

you need to 'synchronise' updates to the that. use the Lock
from multiprocessing import Lock, create a  lock = multiprocessing.Lock(), then the processes need to acquire 'with lock:' .... that to do updates on the shared resource , there's plenty of examples online ...
